Generalized $\ell^p$ space
Forgive me if this is discussed somewhere, I wasn't able to find anything on it. I am learning basic functional analysis and am trying to further understand $L^p$ spaces. When $\mu$ is the counting measure, we know the inclusions between the corresponding $L^p(\mathbb{N}, \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}), \mu)$ spaces, namely if $0<p<q\leq \infty$ we have $\ell^p\subset \ell^q$.
But, what if we change the counting measure slightly so that it is instead $\mu_a(E)=\sum_{n\in E}n^a$ for some $a\in\mathbb{R}$? Then we can consider the identity map on the space of finitely supported sequences, and try to extend it as a bounded linear operator from $L^p(\mu_a)$ to $L^q(\mu_a)$.
My question is: is there some general result for what values of $p$ and $q$ we can actually perform such an extension? That is, with our modified counting measure, when can we embed $L^p(\mu_a)$ into $L^q(\mu_a)$?

The general result is as follows for any measure space $(X,\mu)$:
Let $1 \leq p < q \leq \infty$. Then we have the following inclusions:

$L^q(\mu) \subseteq L^p(\mu)$ iff there are NOT sets of arbitrarily large finite measure.
$L^p(\mu) \subseteq L^q(\mu)$ iff there are NOT sets of arbitrarily small nonzero measure.

For $a < -1$, the measure is finite, but there are sets of arbitrarily small measure, so  $L^q(\mu) \subseteq L^p(\mu)$ but not the reverse.
For $a \geq 0$, every nonempty set has measure at least $1$, but there are sets of large finite measure, so  $L^p(\mu) \subseteq L^q(\mu)$ but not the reverse. This includes the standard counting measure at $a=0$.
For $-1 \leq a < 0$, the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^a$ diverges, but $n^a \to 0$. So there are no such inclusions.

Makes a lot of sense, thank you!
